Query posts which are related via postmeta
I have two custom posts type: course and teacher.
A course can be related to one or more teachers.
Relations are postmeta containing teacher post id.
I need to be able to filter courses list inside admin edit page looking for teacher post title containing the name of the teacher.
I'm trying with filters on posts_join and posts_where but I can proceed because every example teach how to join posts and postmetas but I need further query to full related posts.

using raw SQL or trying to modify the SQL generated is unnecessary and highly unusual, unless you're interacting with a 3rd party table writing SQL is usually a big warning sign that something has gone wrong in WP development, especially when you're trying to modify queries to WordPress core tables. The docs for WP_Query should contain the answer you're looking for, but keep in mind that post meta tables are not optimised for this, you'd have been better off storing your relation as a term in a taxonomy not a meta value, searching for posts via their meta values doesn't scale

Seconding what Tom's saying, querying by postmeta is hideously slow and is absolutely not the right approach here. Taxonomies are indexed because they're designed for querying and filtering posts.
